# AttributeError: 'float' object has no attribute 'append' when trying to append values to existing key

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

Trying to append float values to the same key in defaultdic type dictionary.

```py
from collection import defaultdict

new_dict= defaultdict(list)

for row in list_dict:
    acct=row[acct]
    time_spent= float(row[time_spent])

    if (acct not in new_dict):
        new_dict[acct] = time_spent
    else:
        new_dict[acct].append(time_spent)
```

gives me error:

```py
AttributeError: 'float' object has no attribute 'append'
```

If I remove float,

```py
time_spent= float(row[time_spent])
```

gives me,

```py
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'append'
```

I have to add those time_spent in the list of values later so I would like them to be float.

Answer (score 0):

When `acct` isn't in `new_dict`, you assign a float value (`time_spent`) to the new key. Since you are using a `defaultdict` that will automatically create an empty `list` the first time the key is read, you should remove the check, and unconditionally `append` the new value:

```py
time_spent= float(row[time_spent])
new_dict[acct].append(time_spent)
```